# How to create new column 'Status' in through the action button 'create column' in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a R shiny app that reads many xpt files and displays the data in a table, it works fine at present.

To extend this app I want to create a new column called "status" with empty values by clicking the action button "add column" after the xpt files have been uploaded. To do this, I created a "function" called "new column" and called it in to the server with "observeEvent," but it currently does not work; instead, I am getting the following error.

**Note:** Once the column 'status' is created, I should be able to edit/add the column values.

**Error**

```
Warning: Error in <-: object 'cur_df' not found
```

**code**

```
library(shiny)
library(haven)
library(stringr)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)


#function this creates new column to a datatable
new_column <- function(df, colname) {
  df$status <- " "
  
  return(df)
}

new_column(dat)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv", ".xpt"
                )
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      uiOutput("files_available"),
      uiOutput("filters"),
      
      actionButton("addcolumn", "create column")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tables")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  nms <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  suffixes <- c("STUDYID", "DOMAIN", "VALUE")
  
  df <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    input$file1$datapath %>%
      map(~ read_xpt(.x))
  })
  
  # for debugging
  observe({
    print(df())
    # print(nms())
    # print(map(names(input), ~input[[.x]]))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(df(), {
    nms(map(df(), names))
  })
  
  output$filters <- renderUI({
    req(df())
    inpts <- tagList(
      numericInput("STUDYID", "STUDYID", value = NA),
      textInput("DOMAIN", "DOMAIN", value = ""),
      numericInput("VALUE", "VALUE", value = NA)
    )
  })
  
  output$tables <- renderUI({
    req(df())
    map(1:length(df()), ~ tableOutput(str_c("table", .x)))
  })
  
  observeEvent(c(input$STUDYID, input$DOMAIN, input$VALUE), {
    df <- df()
    # df contains multiple dataframes so we need to loop through each of them to create the render functions
    walk(1:length(df), ~ {
      output[[str_c("table", .x)]] <<- renderTable({
        cur_df <- df[[.x]]
        nms <- nms()[[.x]]
        nms <- map(suffixes, ~ str_subset(nms, .)) # to order the correct column names with the required input. Warning, if more than one name matches the suffix is not tested
        # first we look if the input is character type and force a NA value on it, if it's not we just look for NA.
        # If the input is not NA (meaning that is has a value inserted by the user), then filter the table by that value.
        walk2(nms, suffixes, ~ {
          if (class(input[[.y]]) == "character") {
            if (input[[.y]] == "") {
              input_value <- NA
            } else {
              input_value <- input[[.y]]
            }
          } else {
            input_value <- input[[.y]]
          } # empty textInput's show has an empty string value instead of NA
          print(input_value)
          if (!is.na(input_value)) {
            cur_df <<- cur_df %>% filter(.data[[.x]] == input[[.y]])
          }
        })
        cur_df
      })
    })
  })
  
  
  #this server function creates new column with the existing datatable "cur_df"
  observeEvent(input$addcolumn, {
    df1 <- new_column(cur_df)
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `df` will be modified at multiple places of your code, you can not use `reactive` anymore. Initialize `df` with `reactiveVal` instead:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

# example data
# to be replaced by read_csv(input_path)
init_df <- iris

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("addcolumn", "add column"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <- reactiveVal(value = init_df)

  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$addcolumn,
    handlerExpr = {
      df() %>%
        add_column(status = "") %>%
        df()
    }
  )

  output$table <- renderTable(df())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you. But When I substitute this with my original code (Initial Post), I can see this error `Error in reactiveVal(value = cur_df) : object 'cur_df' not found
Warning in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork)`

Comment: The argument `value` must be present on startup of the server function. `cur_df` will be created later

Comment: Could you help me with the updated code?

Comment: Your question is not updated yet.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Since I am new to R shiny, could you perhaps assist me with creating a new column using the data frame `cur_df`?

Comment: You have a list of data frames (one per csv file). Do you want to add the column and display all the tables?

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Comment: Can you help me on this?

Comment: This is something which is hard for me to debug and should be doable by you. Shiny is well documented. They have lots of tutorials.

Comment: I haven't worked with xpt files but adding a new column to an existing table (DB or in a file) should use bind_cols /cbind and then the users should see the data in an editable format (or editable in UI with inputs or other methods of choice). Have u checked DT package wit its dataTableProxy etc to udpate data? I can try to workout a simple app to show functionality with a csv file with adding a column (I have idea in mind but need time to code). 1 question : Will the "Add Column" be user action driven only or we can do that at the time of file upload? This changes the flow and work.

Comment: With your code soem problems:  in your  new_column() there is argument for colname, which is not needed since you are adding the column "status" to your df. (I corrected it and it works `new_column <- function(df)`) Also when you call it with cur_df its not accessible since you have defined cur_df only  inside an observeEven adn not globally..  `cur_df <- reactiveValues(data =NULL)` 3rd when you are updating with new column addition , you generate df1 but there is no way to display it- should it not replace the df().  I think you need to change the code a lot inlcuding the design part.

Comment: `add_column(status = "")` creates indeed an empty column, as it was required in the question. Note, that my answer does not contain `cur_df`. `df` is accessible / display by calling  `df()` in the complete scope of function `server`.  Please look at the documentation  https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.3.0/reactiveVal.html

Comment: @anuanand, it would be great  if you provide me the code with your solutions updated,

Comment: @anuanand, to answer your "1question: Will the "Add Column" be user action driven only or we can do that at the time of file upload? This changes the flow and work. : " `my answer follows:`  Yes, it is pretty much users  driven, users can create any number of columns that they want which should be in a editable format